# Search Bar based on JSON not working

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

I have a TableViewController and array from JSON url. I wanted to search @Name from server.Tableview showing data were well.But searching does not working.How to do it ?Where is the mistake?

**Tableviewcontroller.h :**

```
    @interface CitiesViewController ()
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *jsonArray
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *citiesArray;

   @property (nonatomic, copy)NSMutableArray *filteredNames;
   @property (nonatomic, strong)UISearchController *searchController;          
   @property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayPlace;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searcBar;

        -(void)retrieveData;
```

**Tableviewcontroller.m :**

```
     @end

        @implementation CitiesViewController
        @synthesize 

citiesArray,jsonArray,filteredNames,arrayPlace,searcBar,searchController;


    #pragma mark -

    #pragma mark Class Methods


    -(void)retrieveData
    {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];



        citiesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i= 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *cID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *cName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString *cCompany = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"company"];
            NSString *cPosition = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"position"];
            NSString *cEmail = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"email"];

            NSString *cNumber = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"number"];
            NSString *cPhoto = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo"];


            NSURL *urlOne = [NSURL URLWithString:cPhoto];
       //     NSLog(@"%@",urlOne);
            NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOne];
            UIImage *imageOne = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];

            [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc]initWithCityName:cName andCityState:cCompany andCityCountry:cEmail andCityPopulation:cPosition andCityID:cID andCityNumber:cNumber andCityPhoto: (UIImage *) imageOne]];

        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

       [self retrieveData];

        self.arrayPlace = [NSMutableArray new];

        UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        filteredNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]init];

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;   

    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return 1;
        }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (tableView.tag == 1) {  

            return citiesArray.count;
        } else {

            return [filteredNames count];
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

        if (tableView.tag == 1){
        City *cityob;
        cityob=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=cityob.employeeName;
        }else{
            cell.textLabel.text = filteredNames[indexPath.row];
        }

        return cell;

    }


    #pragma mark Search Display Delegate Methods

    -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

    {

        [filteredNames removeAllObjects];
        if (searchString.length > 0) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searcBar.text];

            for (NSString *name in citiesArray) {
                NSArray *matches = [[self.jsonArray[name] objectForKey:@"Name"]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                [filteredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

            }
            NSLog(@"filteredNames==%@",filteredNames);

        }


        return YES;

    }
```

Comment: Try with `SELF.ABC CONTAINS %@"`, where `ABC` is the property name in `City` corresponding of `Name` (case sensitive) and just use it doing: `filteredName = [citiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];` ?

Comment: @Larme    
Not working!more details can be